# I cannot get a COOKIE to update it's value (which is an integer)

Tags: php, cookies

I have been working on this for so long now, I feel this is my last option, I have a slideshow on a html web page and they can essentially flick through all the way through to the end by scrolling.  Essentially I want users to be able to go back to their dashboard and when they click to go back into the slideshow, to re-load the page they were on...

At the top  of the page I have this:

```
    <?php
  if (!isset($_COOKIE['PageNo'])){
    setcookie("PageNo", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day, so set the cookie for a month long period
  }
?>
```

I am essentially saying set the cookie at 1 to begin with (the first page in the slideshow = 1, then above the next section I have the below:

```
<?php

    if($_COOKIE['PageNo'] >= 2) 
  {
    ?>

    <script>
      window.location.replace("<?php echo "istudy_university.php#slide=".$_COOKIE['PageNo']; ?> ");
    </script>

<?php
  }
    else
  { 
?>
  <script>
      window.location.replace("istudy_university.php#slide=1");
  </script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Above each slide I have the below and just changing the slide=number:

```
<?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 3; ?>
```

So I'm saying, if the cookie is more than or equal to 2, then go to the page no'x' else go to page 1. However all it keeps doing is bringing me back constantly to Page 1. Please help!! Am I setting the cookie wrong?

UPDATE: After sliding through some of the slides, the cookie should have changed to 5, however it's still 1?

[image]

***UPDATED code showing the HTML for page:***

```
        <?php
      session_start();
      require "includes/dbh.inc.php";
    ?>

    <?php
    echo $_COOKIE['PageNo'];
      //$_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 5; //Commented out, for testing
      if (!isset($_COOKIE['PageNo'])){
        setcookie("PageNo", 1, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day, so set the cookie for a month long period
      }
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>iStudy University | Stress & Anxiety</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' media='all' href="webslides.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <body>

        <script src="static/js/webslides.js"></script>

         <!-- BEGINNING OF SLIDES -->
         <?php

          if($_COOKIE['PageNo'] >= 2) 
          {
            ?>

            <script>
              window.location.replace("<?php echo "istudy_university.php#slide=".$_COOKIE['PageNo']; ?> ");
            </script>

        <?php
          }
            else
          { 
        ?>
          <script>
              window.location.replace("istudy_university.php#slide=1");
          </script>
        <?php
          }
        ?>
        <main role="main">
          <article id="webslides">
            <!-- SLIDE 1 -->

            <section class="bg-apple aligncenter">
             <span class="background dark" style="background-image: url('istudy_slides_images/abstract.jpg')"/></span>
              <div class="wrap" id="slide=1">
                <h1 class="text-landing">Stress & Anxiety</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <hr id="hor-rule">
                <h1 class="slides-logo">iStudy University <i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></h1>
                <h2 class="slogan">Designed by Students <br><span class="iv">IV</span> <br>Students</h2><br><br>
              </div>
            </section>

            <!-- SLIDE 2 -->
            <?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 2; ?>
            <section class="aligncenter">
              <span class="background light" style="background-image: url('istudy_slides_images/mountain.jpg')"/></span>
              <div class="wrap" id="slide=2">
                <blockquote class="quote">
                  <p class>"No one can create negativity or stress within you. Only you can do that by virtue of how you process your world"</p>
                  <p><cite>Wayne Dyer</cite></p>
                </blockquote>
              </div>
            </section>

        <!-- SLIDE 3 -->
        <?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 3; ?>
        <section class="bg-slide3">
          <div class="wrap size-80" id="slide=3">
            <h3 class="title stessAnx"><strong>&ensp;Stress & Anxiety</strong></h3><br>
              <p>Stress and anxiety are common experiences of students in higher education.<br>This module will introduce you to evidence based techniques for managing stress and anxiety based upon cognitive behavioural therapy (CBT).</p>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Has the cookie been saved? Can you confirm its value by checking through the browser or dumping `$_COOKIE['PageNo']`.

Comment: Setting cookies in PHP can be a bit messy, have a look at the documentation and examples here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php they may be of help

Comment: Hi @Script47 The cookie number doesn't changes for some reason, when I view page source it's ALWAYS 1. To test it worked I placed `<?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 3; ?>` at the very top of the php code and it did bring me straight to page 5, however when I set the cookie above each slide, it doesn't want to work :(

Comment: @T.C You don't seem to increment the $_COOKIE['PageNo'] value.

Comment: Hello @akshithDayanand I just automatically set it for each slide i.e. above one slide I placed `<?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 3; ?>`, then the next slide has this at the top `<?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 4; ?>` so on so forth?

Comment: Outputting plain cookie contents is a security concern. At least use `htmlentities()` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include jQuery library in both dashboard and slides page.
Include [Scrollify](https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify) library in the slides page

In the dashboard page, add an id to the slide page navigation link, like:

```
<a  id="home" href="#">Slides</a>
```

Modify the sections in your slides page as follows:

- Add a unique ID and a common class name for all the sections.

Example:

```
<section class="slides aligncenter" id="b">
        <span class="background light" style="background-image: url('istudy_slides_images/mountain.jpg')" /></span>
        <div class="wrap" id="slide=2">
            <blockquote class="quote">
                <p class>"No one can create negativity or stress within you. Only you can do that by virtue of how you process your world"</p>
                <p><cite>Wayne Dyer</cite></p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- SLIDE 3 -->
    <section class="slides bg-slide3" id="c">
        <div class="wrap size-80" id="slide=3">
            <h3 class="title stessAnx"><strong>&ensp;Stress & Anxiety</strong></h3><br>
            <p>Stress and anxiety are common experiences of students in higher education.<br>This module will introduce you to evidence based techniques for managing stress and anxiety based upon cognitive behavioural therapy (CBT).</p>
    </section>
```

** The id for each section is given as 'b', 'c' etc.

** both section contains a common class name - 'slides'.

In the slides page, add the following JavaScript code in the footer.

```
$.scrollify({
    section: ".slides", //Rename the class name with the common class name that you gave for the sections
    after: function() {

        localStorage.setItem('currentPage', $.scrollify.current()[0].id)

    }
});
```

In the dashboard page, add the below JavaScript code to the footer at the end:

```
 <script>
      if(localStorage.getItem('currentPage') != ''){
          var newUrl = 'scroll.html#'+localStorage.getItem('currentPage');
        $("#home").attr("href", newUrl);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Every time I go back to the homepage, then back into the slideshow it should remember which number slide I'm on (if cookie has been saved ok), however it goes straight back to 1. Is my concatenation I've done maybe incorrectly? :(

Comment: @T.C even after using the above coed instead of <?php $_COOKIE['PageNo'] = 3; ?> above each slide to update the cookie , are you facing the issue??

Comment: So I've placed this at the top of every section `<?php setcookie("PageNo", 3, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');  ?>` , `<?php setcookie("PageNo", 4, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');  ?>` and it's still bringing me back to 1

Comment: @T.C are you setting any cookie value in home page?Show the home page code if you caould

Comment: The dashboard page (after-login.php) the user goes on to access the slideshow has no cookies set at all in there, the slideshow page (slides.php) is where the php code and cookies exist (as seen in question), do you want me add cookies in the dashboard? We can chat online if helpful to save writing in comments?

Comment: @T.C Could you show the code where you have the different slides section and where you update the cookie value

Comment: @T.C you cant modify php cookie value by scrolling though the page. That's why you have an issue setting the cookie value. My suggestion would be to use ajquey plugin like https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/ and then store the url hash value to browsers localstorage. Once stored, modify the page url according to the value stored

Comment: Wow ok, that sounds mega complicated, is there an easy to-do explanation on this please, I'm such a newbie and my deadline is so close now. Panic Mode set in

Comment: @T.C haha..I'll try to update my code to get you started

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191274/discussion-between-t-c-and-akshithdayanand).